# onSuccess and onFailure doesn't return anything when they are last statement in def

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scalaz

I am trying to work with collection of futures and having trouble with returning the result from a def based on future status. Below is my code:

```
final case class StagesToRun(stages : Set[StageRun])
private def processNextStagesAndAccumulateResults(stagesToRun: StagesToRun): \/[Exception, Success] = {
val stageProcessingExceptions = mutable.Set[Exception]()
//processor.process(stagesToRun) => returns a Set[Future[\/[Exception, Success]]] and I am converting it to  Future[Set[\/[Exception, Success]]] in below expression
val processResults = Future.sequence(processor.process(stagesToRun))
processResults.onSuccess {
  case result => {
    result.map { res =>
      res.fold(
        l => stageProcessingExceptions += l,
        r => r
      )
    }
    if (stageProcessingExceptions.isEmpty) Success.right
    else new Exception("Got exception while processing one of the stage").left
  }
}
processResults.onFailure {
  case ex =>  new Exception(ex.getMessage)).left
}
}
```

Now as per Scala conventions the last statement of my function becomes the return statement of my function. In this function it should be basically the output of `if (stageProcessingExceptions.isEmpty) Success` and its corresponding `else` or the outcome of `onFailure` i.e `new Exception(ex.getMessage))`. However the compiler keeps on telling me that the return type is unit rather than expected disjunction. Can someone please help me here? Thanks

Comment: `onSuccess ` and `onFailure` are not designed to return. They are designed to catch  result without blocking the rest of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely correct when you say that the last statement of the function becomes the return statement. However, if you see the method definition of `onSuccess` and `onFailure`, both of them return `Unit` as the return type.

From scala docs, signature of onSuccess is

```
def onSuccess[U](pf: PartialFunction[T, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit = onComplete {
    case Success(v) =>
      pf.applyOrElse[T, Any](v, Predef.identity[T]) // Exploiting the cached function to avoid MatchError
    case _ =>
  }
```

On similar lines onFailure returns unit.

```
 def onFailure[U](@deprecatedName('callback) pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit = onComplete {
    case Failure(t) =>
      pf.applyOrElse[Throwable, Any](t, Predef.identity[Throwable]) // Exploiting the cached function to avoid MatchError
    case _ =>
  }
```

In your situation what you can do is to apply a map function on the future and instead of onComplete. This will help you to propagate your required type.
Also, if you want to handle the condition where your future is failing, you can add a recover block to your future as

```
 .recover {
          case _ =>
         //whatever type you want to propogate ex: Left()
        }
```

Comment: thanks for  your response. Map worked perfectly as I was expecting.

Answer (score 3):

Both `onSuccess` and `onFailure` return `Unit` and are designed for implementing side-effects. If you want to return a modified `Future`, use `transform`. One version of this takes two functions: The first function processes successful results and the second processes exceptions.

```
processResults.transform(
  { result =>
    // process result and return new result
    // throw error on failure
    result
  },
  { ex =>
    // Process exception and return new exception
    ex
  }
)
```

If you throw an exception in either function you will get an error `Future`.

There is another version of `transform` which takes a function `Try => Try` which allows you to turn an error `Future` into a success `Future` which is not possible with the version above.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for your response, I tried transform and map both. Now I know how both works :)